# Powershell Argument List Based On Condition

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-2.0, command-line-arguments

I want to make a argument Mandatory based on the Switch Condition
Something Like

```
param(
[string]$para1,
[switch]$choice="Upgrade"
[string]$paraUpg 
[string]$paraInstall 
)
```

now if the choice is `Upgrade` I want to make `$paraUpg` mandatory and if `$choice` is `Install` then `$paraInstall` has to be mandatory

Comment: Please show us what you've done.

Comment: Actually I want something like
param(
[string]$para1,
[switch]$choice="Upgrade"
[string]$paraUpg
[string]$paraInstall
)

now if the choice is Upgrade I want to Make $paraUpg Mandatory and if Choice is Install then $paraInstall has to be mandatory

Comment: You can add this new info to your question and it meets the criteria that you have tried something and people won't down vote it (maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following.  Setup all of your parameters and if `$choice="Upgrade"` and `$paraUpg` is null or empty throw an exception.  Repeat similarly for `$choice="Install"`.  You could then conditionally choose what to do after the parameter check based on the parameters chosen.

```
param(
    [string]$para1,
    [string]$choice="Upgrade",
    [string]$paraUpg,
    [string]$paraInstall
    )

#check if choice is "Upgrade" and paraUpg is empty
if(($choice -eq "Upgrade") -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($paraUpg)))
{
    throw "paraUpg is a required parameter"
}
#check if choice is "Install" and paraInstall is empty
elseif (($choice -eq "Install") -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($paraInstall)) )
{
    throw "paraInstall is a required parameter"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all its `PowerShell` which comes along with windows 7 as one of its added utilities.

you have not given any detail about what have you done so far. I suspect you want something like this.

in your `PowerShell` script declare params preferably at top.

```
param([string]$UserName, [string]$Password, [string]$MachineName)
```

use these parmas within your powershell script wherever required. Now create a batch file from where you can pass values to these params like this.

```
@powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -FILE YourPowerShellScript.ps1 "UserName" "Password" "MachineName"
```

i have specified Policy rights within batch file so you don't have to mention each time when you run the script on different machines. Hope it helps.

Comment: My problem is that when the Powershell script is invoked from the Batch it asks for a continue because the script is not signed.I want to bypass that Confirmation

Comment: In my response, i have mentioned `ExecutionPolicy` rights to `Unrestricted` within argument batch file which will handle your case. you can either set it to `Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned`.